# apply a condition in all rows of a table in the mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Table "**course**":

| course_name | course_id |
| --- | --- |
| Math1 | 10 |
| English | 15 |
| Physic1 | 20 |
| C++ | 25 |
| Basketball | 30 |
| Physic2 | 35 |
| Math2 | 40 |
| Algebra | 45 |
| Software Architecture | 50 |
| Algorithms | 55 |
| Operating Systems | 60 |
| Statistic and Probability | 65 |

Table "**stco**":

| student_firstname | course_id | course_status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Melika | 65 | passed |
| Melika | 60 | passed |
| Melika | 55 | passed |
| Melika | 50 | passed |
| Melika | 45 | passed |
| Melika | 40 | passed |
| Melika | 35 | passed |
| Mahzad | 60 | passed |
| Mahzad | 65 | faild |
| Mahzad | 10 | faild |
| Mahzad | 20 | faild |
| Mahzad | 25 | passed |
| Mahzad | 30 | faild |
| Mahzad | 35 | passed |
| Mahzad | 40 | faild |
| Mahzad | 45 | passed |
| Mahzad | 50 | passed |
| Mahzad | 55 | faild |
| Fakhri | 65 | passed |
| Fakhri | 60 | passed |
| Fakhri | 55 | passed |
| Fakhri | 50 | passed |
| Fakhri | 45 | faild |
| Fakhri | 40 | faild |
| Fakhri | 35 | passed |
| Fakhri | 30 | faild |
| Fakhri | 25 | passed |
| Fakhri | 20 | passed |
| Fakhri | 15 | faild |
| Fakhri | 10 | faild |

Table "**student**":

| student_lastname | student_id | student_firstname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Seyedalikhani | 1 | Mahzad |
| Karami | 2 | Fakhri |
| Ahmadi | 3 | Melika |

I want to write \a query that shows the courses that no-body couldn't pass them. In the below i put my query. but it doesn't work. what should I do?

```
SELECT course_name,count(course_name)
FROM course c
JOIN st_co st
    ON st.course_id = c.course_id
JOIN student s
    ON st.student_firstname = s.student_firstname
group by course_name
having sum(st.course_id IN (10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65)
    And st.course_status = 'failed' )
```

Comment: Can you share sample input tables and expected output?

Answer (score 2):

how about a not exists

```
   select course_name from course c
    where not exists ( 
        select 1 from st_co where st_co.course_id = c.course_id 
        and st.course_status != 'failed')
```

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: There's a typo in the filtering condition, fixing it should make this work properly: `and st_co.course_status != 'failed'` >> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3YwyC7QVJPZZdntu2TZ5n8/0.